# How Schwartz switch to the new variables in integration but left some of old variables untouched?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, integration, scattering-cross-section

In Section 5.1.2 of Schwartz's when he changes variables from Equation 5.27 to Equation 5.29 he left a piece of old variables and treat it as constant. Shouldn't $p_f$ also be replaced with some expression $p_f(x)$?

The relevant equations are reproduced below; $E_3=\sqrt{m_3^2+p_f^2}$ and $E_4=\sqrt{m_4^2+p_f^2}$
\begin{align}
\tag{5.27}\mathrm d\Pi_{LIPS}&=\frac{1}{16\pi^2}\mathrm d\Omega \int\mathrm dp_f \frac{p_f^2}{E_3E_4}\delta(E_3+E_4-E_\text{CM})\\
\text{Introducing}\qquad x(p_f)&=E_3(p_f)+E_4(p_f)-E_\text{CM}\\
\tag{5.28}\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dp_f}=\frac{\mathrm d\ \ }{\mathrm dp_f}(E_3+E_4-E_\text{CM})&=\frac{p_f}{E_3}+\frac{p_f}{E_4}=\frac{E_3+E_4}{E_3E_4}p_f\qquad\text{(Jacobian)}\\
\mathrm d\Pi_{LIPS}&=\frac{1}{16\pi^2}\mathrm d\Omega\int\mathrm dx \frac{p_f}{E_{CM}}\delta(x)\\
\tag{5.29}&=\frac1{16\pi^2}\mathrm d\Omega\frac{p_f}{E_\text{CM}}\theta(E_\text{CM}-m_3-m_4)
\end{align}

Comment: Welcome. Please don't post images containing text or equations that are essential to understand the question, please transcribe everything that's necessary (You can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for equations).

Comment: I can see why the OP did it in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's elementary calculus, or, rather, notation. $p_f$ is not a real variable, as it is constraint to the constant enforced by the δ-function constraint: the integration is fake/illusory!  The author is aiming to collapse the δ-function, so he switches, locally invertibly, to $x(p_f)$ from $p_f$. The expression he left, as you noticed, is actually its inverse function, $p_f(x)$, a function of *x* in reality, with the original name retained, but, as originally, it is fixed to a constant by the vanishing of the δ-function argument.

He can now collapse the δ-function, given the transformed lower limit of the  integral, into a step function (some *x*s are disallowed as being out of that range!). If you wish, you may now "remember" the function $p_f(0)$ as the original constant $p_f$, as the variable *x* has disappeared with the integration, and you need not recall it anymore. You may now luxuriate in the simplicity of equation (5.32).